# App submission: No binary but getting "redundant binary" error

Tags: error, app-store-connect

When submitting the first release of my app for review on iTunesConnect, I'm getting a validation error that I need to upload a binary, but when I upload using Application Loader 3.0 I get an error ITMS-4238 "Redundant binary upload".

Validation error:

[image: upload a binary]

Upload error:
[image: error ITMS-4238 "Redundant binary upload"]

This happened after I uploaded the binary last week, filled in some of the app details, saved the page, came back to it today, completed the rest of the app details, and clicked "Submit for Review."

Any ideas how to fix this?

Unlike post #146330, I don't have another binary I want to submit - I want to use the one that's already uploaded. Unfortunately iTunesConnect doesn't seem to recognize there is one. I also don't have the source code and can't change the version or build number in Xcode because it was coded by a paid vendor.

Comment: I read that one first, but it doesn't apply here - I don't want to submit a 2nd binary

Comment: Unfortunately that's the solution here. You'll need to upload the binary with a new build number.

Comment: I get the impression my question wasn't read thoroughly. I don't have the source code - can't change the build number. I'm not trying to submit an updated binary. I'm looking for a different solution.

Comment: Not having the source code doesn't make the duplicate *not* the correct answer.

Comment: I'm not trying to upload a new binary. I want to use the one that apparently is already uploaded. How do I get iTunesConnect to use that one?

Comment: While I accept uploading a new binary with an incremented build version may solve the problem, my stated limitation makes it impractical. It might be easier for me to rename the app record and starting with a new one.